# Use variable outside nested function

Tags: python, function, variables, tkinter

My code uses a tkinter entry box inside of a function to retrieve an IP address from a user.  When the button is pressed the ip address is assigned to the variable (server_ip).  This variable is used later in the code to set up a socket connection.  My issue is that I can't use the variable outside of the main function.

```
import tkinter as tk

def get_server_ip():
    def retrieve_server_ip():
        server_ip = ent_ip.get()
        home.destroy()
        return server_ip

    home = tk.Tk()
    home.title("Enter Server Ip Address")
    home.geometry('100x75')

    lbl_ip = tk.Label(home, text="Enter Server IP")
    lbl_ip.pack()
    ent_ip = tk.Entry(home)
    ent_ip.pack()
    btn_enter = tk.Button(home, text="Enter", command=retrieve_server_ip)
    btn_enter.pack()

    tk.mainloop()
    
get_server_ip()
print (server_ip)
```

Answer (score 0):

[Declare that the variable is a global before using it](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-global-statement), like so:

```
def get_server_ip():
    def retrieve_server_ip():
        global server_ip
        server_ip = ent_ip.get()
        home.destroy()
        return server_ip
```

Answer (score -1):

You can return the value from the function instead:

```
import tkinter as tk

def get_server_ip():
    server_ip = None
    def retrieve_server_ip():
        nonlocal server_ip
        server_ip = ent_ip.get()
        home.destroy()

    home = tk.Tk()
    home.title("Enter Server Ip Address")
    home.geometry('100x75')

    lbl_ip = tk.Label(home, text="Enter Server IP")
    lbl_ip.pack()
    ent_ip = tk.Entry(home)
    ent_ip.pack()
    btn_enter = tk.Button(home, text="Enter", command=retrieve_server_ip)
    btn_enter.pack()

    tk.mainloop()
    return server_ip
    
server_ip = get_server_ip()
print (server_ip)
```

Comment: You code will get `None` as `server_ip` is a local variable inside `retrieve_server_ip()` function.  Add `nonlocal server_ip` inside that function.

Comment: Thanks that did the trick.  For some reason I've never heard of a nonlocal variable until you mentioned it.  Can't believe I missed that.